# Suppress Notifications from a different app

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'd like to implement an application which is able to suppress notifications generated by other apps; basically I want to build a more customize-able version of the "do not disturb" functionality that ships with Android, such that I can do things like block certain apps at certain times of day, or suppress notifications from an app entirely at certain times of day (in other words, not just prevent the phone from buzzing but prevent the notification from appearing at all).

However looking at the available APIs I don't believe this is possible.  NotificationListenerService will allow me to hear about notifications and cancel / mark them as seen them after the fact, but not intercept them and make a determination about whether or not they should be shown in the first place.  The best it looks like I could do is cancel the notification quickly after hearing about it.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: You need to include some code or show us what you have tried

Comment: FYI this will be hard after last update, something like that required very long background process since every application have it's own scheduled background process, how you can reschedule your app to be compatible with all these apps notification time?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, since I can't find any API that seems to expose what I'm looking for (which is essentially what I'm asking: does such an API exist outside of NotificationListenerService).